# Looking for a replacement for NMS FormMail.pl

Tags: php, perl, webforms, formmail

I have a simple contact form that I knocked up in a few minutes using [NMS FormMail.pl](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml).  But the customer has requested that I have a second email address entry field, and validation that kicks them back if the two addresses are different.  I could add the validation to FormMail.pl, but before I do, I thought I'd ask if there is a better solution, if only because this might already be a solved problem, and also because nobody has modified FormMail.pl in 4+ years.

I know this server has perl and PHP, and maybe Python as well.  I've also got Tomcat running, but a servlet seems like overkill for this.

Comment: Got any links for this FormMail.pl script?

Answer (score 3):

Far simpler to just add the validation to NMSFormMail than start again with a whole other solution. And maybe nobody's modified it because it just doesn't need modifying?

Do you need help modifying the script?

Answer (score 1):

NMS FormMail.pl hasn't been modified by the original authors because it's such a simple thing. It's simply done.

I would suggest you just add a new form entry field and compare the two using Perl's string comparison operator 'eq'.

Comment: It isn't the comparing that's the problem, it's then producing some sort of error page, etc.